# Printing only specific details from another website using cURL

Tags: php

I am using this PHP code to display some data from another web page using get_data($url) and it works fine. Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    function get_data($url, $post='')
    {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        if(!empty($post))
       {
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,$url);
       }
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,realpath('.').'/cookies.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,realpath('.').'/cookies.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
        return curl_exec($ch);
    }
    set_time_limit(0);
    $min = $_GET['min'];
    $max = $_GET['max'];
    for ($i=$min; $i<=$max; $i++)
    {
            $url = 'http://main.com/login.php?access=/even_detail.php?tid=' . $i;
            get_data($url);
            $post = '&user=admin&pass=admin';
            echo get_data($url, $post)."<br />";
    }
    ?>
```

And for example this is the HTML of [the link](http://main.com/login.php?access=/even_detail.php?tid=):

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div align="left">
    <pre>
    Array
    (
        [dst_eventId] => 123
        [dst_eventState] => MD
        [dst_eventZip] => 12345
        [dst_eventHowManyKids] => 20
        [dst_eventHowManyAdults] => 5
        [dst_evenHolder] => Willcock
    )
    </pre>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now i want to display on my page with my php code above using get_data() for these rows (not all rows)

```
        [dst_eventId] => 123
        [dst_eventState] => MD
        [dst_evenHolder] => Willcock
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What makes these rows special? Also, please don't litter with your question with useless bold formatting. Use **bold** only when you want to emphasize something. You certainly don't want to emphasize *everything* in your question.

Comment: I just used these rows for example. And I am new here. Excutes me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: can you please continue my code above. And the data i load is from .php url